# Learning C++ Language

Tags: c++

I am a .net c# programmer but I want to learn .NET C++ also. I am a beginner for c++. Is there any site, book, or Video Tutorials from beginner to expert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no such thing as ".Net c++".

Maybe you mean **C++/CLI**, which is Microsoft's language specification intended to supersede Managed Extensions for C++ (See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C%2B%2B/CLI)). **Managed extensions to C++** are its inferior and now defunct ancestor [thanks @dp for your comment].

Bear in mind when you choose your learning material that C++/CLI is not equal to the (standard) **C++** programming language; so if you want to learn the former, you should edit the question title and tags.

(Note: This is not to be nitpicky, but to help. I think getting the right idea for each name, and the right name for each concept, is an important factor for consistent learning. And of course it's especially important if you search for information on the web.)

Comment: And also note that C++/CLI is not the same as the now defunct and inferior Managed C++.

Comment: Good comment, dp, I'll edit my answer to reflect on that too.

Comment: So C++ is not equal to C++/CLI . So i need to make my own Command Buttons Windows Forms with Codes in C++.Sorry i do not know anything about C++.I always thinked MS Visual C++ is the same of C++ that ya talked.But i wanna learn real C++ language that father of all programming languages.

Comment: @IbrahimAKGUN Microsoft Visual C++ is the same as C++. (If you wanna be nit-picky, it probably has some very minor differences, but you can disable those.) But MS Visual C++ is not the same as C++/CLI. MS Visual C++ compiles to machine code, and can not interface with .NET languages. C++/CLI compiles to CIL bytecode, and can interface with .NET languages (it is one itself).

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest starting with Bruce Eckel's [Thinking in C++](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) for a start.

It's already around for some time (latest version 2003) but it provides a good path from beginner to the more advanced techniques and interiors of C++. It has also some OO foundations in case you like to want to know more about that basics.

([Master download site](http://www.mindviewinc.com/Books/) for the book)

Answer (score 3):

1. cprogramming.com
2. cplusplus.com

Comment: These have been invaluable to me.

Answer (score 3):

For a beginner I think a good starting place is [C++ Primer](http://books.google.com/books?id=4vRE_Q41ZHEC&dq=c%2B%2B+primer&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=PdSdSYvWNYGCtweFvPWGDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=6&ct=result).  From there I'd recommend Scott Meyers' [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889) books.

Certainly this has been asked before, I just can't find the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Accelerated-Practical-Programming-Example-Depth/dp/020170353X/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1235080299&sr=1-4

is great for c++, you'll know the .net from your c#

Answer (score 0):

The biggest tip: in C# you'd do everything with classes, and in C++, you do anything to do with the Win32 API with function calls.

1. google.com and msdn.microsoft.com are your friends.
2. Never give up. C++ is much more time-consuming to write, and it's easier to make mistakes.
3. As you are writing your programs, look for small examples that do small pieces of what you want to achieve, and study them.