# Resources for learning C++ and C++ IDEs

Tags: c++, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)
>   [Learning C++ Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567323/learning-c-language)

Hello I am just starting to learn C++, does anyone have any suggestions for C++ learning resources, for example books and web sites. In addition, does anyone have any suggestions for IDEs?

Comment: We have [the Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Pick up one of the "Beginner" books and you should be on your way.

Comment: That's not how it works, you just *use* one.  It was designed to be intuitive.  Mastering the IDE has very little to do with mastering the language.

Answer (score 0):

Many years ago I used Bruce Eckel's books - they were not a 100% perfect but they explained things well. And probably the best thing about them now is they are available online for free. http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/docs/books/eckel/

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with any other programming language (like C etc)?
if you are, you should straight away start to get your hands dirty. no use investing more time reading. You can learn more by doing. All you need is to search for "c++ hello world" in google, I do it whenever I want to code in any language.

Websites:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/
http://www.learncpp.com/

IDE:
I am not sure if you need an IDE. Visual Studio is the only IDE I have seen being used for C++ in industry. Eclipse has plugins for all popular languages.
Since you are just learning the language (I am assuming you are using Windows), I would suggested DevCpp.

Other tools:
If Windows: notepad++
If Linux: gedit & g++

Pitfalls:
learning C++ or java doesnt automatically make you good at object oriented programming (OOP). So please try to learn OOP concepts and apply them in these languages.